# Binding treeview to object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Bit new to WPF, so i'm just trying to get my head around some bindings in the context of treeviews. First, some code.

In my main window i add my namespace;

```
xmlns:WPFFM="clr-namespace:WPFFM"
```

My class i'm trying to bind through type;

```
namespace WPFFM
{
    public class Asset
    {
        public string ID;
        public string name;
        public string room;
        public string description;

        public Asset(string AssetID, string AssetName, string AssetRoom, string AssetDescription)
        {
            ID = AssetID;
            name = AssetName;
            room = AssetRoom;
            description = AssetDescription;
        }
    }
}
```

My main class which has my List and it's population;

```
namespace WPFFM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DBConnector dbConnector;
        public static List<Asset> assetList;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Populate();
        }

        public void Populate()
        {
            assetList = new List<Asset>();
            dbConnector = new DBConnector();
            DataTable assetDatatable = new DataTable();


            assetDatatable = dbConnector.GetAssets();

            foreach (DataRow row in assetDatatable.Rows)
            {
                Asset assetToAdd = new Asset(row["assetID"].ToString(), row["assetName"].ToString(), row["assetRoomID"].ToString(), row["assetDescription"].ToString());
                assetList.Add(assetToAdd);
            }


            //assetTreeView.ItemsSource = assetList;

        }

    }
}
```

and finally my treeview XAML;

```
TreeView x:Name="assetTreeView"   ItemsSource="{Binding assetList}">
                                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type WPFFM:Asset}" ItemsSource="{Binding assetList}">

                                            <Grid Background="LightSkyBlue"  Margin="2" Width="100" Height="24">

                                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            </Grid>

                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                </TreeView>
```

I've tried numerous ways to bind, but i'm not having any luck. From what i've gathered i'm binding the treeview to the list of Asset(my class), and my datatype to that of Asset. Then i'm trying to display the "name" property exposed from my Asset class. I'm not really sure where i'm going wrong. Am i missing something stupidly simple?

edit: ignore the fact that some functions might need to be moved from the mainwindow.xaml.cs and whatnot, i'm not going for structure at this point.

Comment: add `DataContext = this;` to your `MainWindow` ctor. Pls also read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode there's a reason why so many people keep bashing on about `MVVM` (cos it really works).

Comment: I'm reading the MVVM stuff : ) Like i said i'm just trying binding stuff at the minute!

Comment: @Viv adding that line still didn't fix my problem : /

Comment: I'm afraid you can't bind on a static field. Make `assetList` a property (not a static one) and, as @Viv said, add `DataContext = this`. It should works.

Comment: changed my list, and also my asset fields to properties and it works : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything WPF binds to must be a property, not a field.
Another thing missing here is DataContext initialization. Without it, binding won't work.

Comment: Works like a charm after changing my class fields to properties : )